# Homebrew - Latest Apple Update broke Java based installs, hadoop, cassandra, hive, etc

Tags: homebrew

I have posted this on Homebrew's site to no avail (http://goo.gl/S4xwF)

Strange thing 5 day's ago, updated Apple (combo update, Xcode, java, iTunes) today. This resulted in having bin icons appearing on the dock for cassandra, hive and hadoop. Performed update/upgrade on brew (no issues from doctor reported) to update to the latest, installed latest command line tools from Xcode - but nothing helps.

The biggest issue is when running hive queries this is launching several task windows which causes window focus to these "bin" windows. So essentially I can't do anything until the processes are completed.

Any suggestions? I can't find anything online, like I said this just started and I've spent almost the entire day researching.

executing this command will spawn these "bin" windows
sh /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1*/bin/start-all.sh

or 
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.cassandra.plist

Here are the results from brew --config

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
HEAD: 5d6df73
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit ivybridge
OS X: 10.8.4-x86_64
Xcode: 4.6.3
CLT: 4.6.0.0.1.1365549073
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 4.2 build 425
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /Users/joshcrosby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Java bin windows in dock
- See Homebrew Post for images, SO won't let me post it, not enough questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apple have solve this issue.

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2013/Jun/msg00055.html

OR

add 
 export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

to  conf/hadoop-env.sh  simply solve the problem.